# LO 7.6.3.2 runs really slow..what to do?

Tags: libreoffice

This is my system

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
LibreOffice LibreOffice 7.6.3.2

I upgraded to 7.6.3.2 recently (from the Ubuntu Software store...this is the latest!) and it is really really slow. Is this because it is a SNAP version? Is there anyway to improve the speed....without going back an reinstalling an earlier version which was running quite well with my set of Calc files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confirmed bug filed against the LibreOffice snap because of its speed issues:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/2027904

The same speed issues don't appear to show up with the .deb package version of LibreOffice, which is currently at version 7.6.4 and can be installed using `sudo apt install libreoffice` (or by searching for deb packages in the App Center).

Comment: Thank you for your help!